# Parsing an xml template using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

So I have a template-like script that I'm trying to parse with jQuery. The issue is that I have certain tags that I want to replace with data, which would normally be fine, but I want to loop over object properties, which makes it significantly more difficult.

I want to rely on external libraries as little as possible, so I'm just using jQuery here. I know Angular would probably help here but I don't know it as well yet.

The template code looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<div id="test">
    <each obj="list">
        <div class="listdiv">
            <span><value>thing</value></span>
            <span><value>thing2</value></span>
            <span><value>thing3</value></span>
            <div>
                <each obj="moreStuff">
                    <span>blah: <value>blah</value></span>
                    <span>foo: <value>foo</value></span>
                </each>
            </div>
        </div>
    </each>
</div>
```

And I want to pass in the following JSON object:

```js
{
    list: [
        { thing: 3, thing2: 4, thing3: 5, moreStuff: [{blah:1, foo:2},{blah:4, foo:6}] },
        { thing: 1, thing2: 1, thing3: 2, moreStuff: [{blah:4, foo:6}] }
    ]
}
```

What I want is it to come out to this:

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="listdiv">
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <div>
            <span>blah: 1</span>
            <span>foo: 2</span>
            <span>blah: 4</span>
            <span>foo: 6</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="listdiv">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <div>
            <span>blah: 4</span>
            <span>foo: 6</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was getting it to work alright with regular expressions but of course it's cleaner to do it with DOM manipulation and it's more extensible to do so as well. The thing that causes trouble is the recursive nature of the `<each>` tags and the fact that the `<value>` tags have to get the data from their parent.

I've tried a ton of ways to do this but every time I either have a recursion issue (infinite recursion and I can't get it to replace things) or it can't pull the data correctly. Is there any way to do this nicely?

Comment: Using [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), yes?

Comment: @TimDown: It's coming in through a `$.ajax` request, but yeah, it's parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried these jQuery plugins

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-an-introduction-to-jquery-templating/

https://github.com/trix/nano

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/converters

Comment: I imagine the first one would be fine. However, I am trying to do this without any external libraries, since I have pretty minimal functionality requirements.

That said, if there is no simple way to do this (these things above are literally all I need for now), then I'll probably use one of the libraries. I'm just trying to minimize dependencies.